# Django ATOMIC_REQUESTS not working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So,

We have this Django Rest Framework application that has some `View`'s methods decorated with `@transaction.atomic`.

Within this app we also have a test which checks this behaviour by mocking an internal call to throw an error while trying to update a model. Currently, the test passes (the changes do not take place due to the error being thrown).

The problem is, we want to drop the decorations and set all transactions to be atomic. In this case we went for the `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` database configuration flag. But upon doing that, the test now fails (the model gets updated!).

We managed to print out the `config.DATABASES` value and the `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` is there, so it should behave accordingly, right? What are we missing?

Comment: Your actual tests would help.

Answer (score 3):

As for now, this is an issue on Django-Rest-Framework, as documented here: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/2034